# Postgres wont use the proper index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have the following table:

```
id       : id
dim_id   : fk
day      : date
value    : int
```

With the following indexes:

```
id             : BTREE
dim_id         : BTREE
dim_id, day    : BTREE
day, value     : BRIN
```

When I make the query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE day = '2019-11-18'
ORDER BY day, value
```

The query takes way too long because the index it uses is the `dim_id, day` and then sorts the result, which completely defeats the purpose of having the `day,value` index. The reason this last index is BRIN and not BTREE, is that otherwise the indexes alone were using 200GB, now is more manageable.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the plan look if you explicitly `select id, day, value` (leaving out `dim_id`)?

Comment: Nothing changes @user212514 :( It's still a Parallel Index Scan using `dim_id, day`

Comment: Try create an index only for `day` and another index for `day ASC , value ASC` and run explain again.

Comment: I just deleted a BTREE index on just `day` because the query was using that index and I want it to use the multi-column one. I already have `day ASC, value ASC` index. Any combination of order by `day (ASC/DESC), value (ASC/DESC)`, fails to use the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index on `dim_id` alone seems useless. You can save space and data modification time by dropping it.

A BRIN index cannot be used to support `ORDER BY`, and it won't work at all unless rows are inserted in index order and there are no updates or deletes on the table.

If that is the case, you can use a BRIN index on `day`. The alternative is a B-tree index on `(day,value)`.

Comment: damn, the order by is the only reason why I need this index. Thanks for the clarification.